# What happens when a Chromebook runs out of internal space?

Tags: storage, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Does it delete the downloads folder first? If I have apps does that data get erased sometimes?

Also, is the Downloads area partitioned separately from app storage, or do the share the same file system limit?

What if the Downloads folder is empty, and yet one of the Chrome apps is still using a lot of storage space?

I've tried searching the internet for an answer, but it seems this is a rare occurrence.

Comment: Related: [How can I check the internal storage used by a particular Chromebook app?](http://superuser.com/questions/1132275/how-can-i-check-the-internal-storage-used-by-a-particular-chromebook-app)

Comment: When it runs out of space the files cannot be created an error will be thrown